# Load file to NSData with C

Tags: objective-c, c-libraries

Problem is to load image file to UIImage.
Original file cashed in file system and managed by **C-library** (question about it).

With objective-C I can do so:

```
NSData *file = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:...];
[UIImage imageWithData:file];
```

But how it possible to load file data to objective-C with C?

With C I can open file this like:

```
ret = fopen( name, options);
```

But can I use the **ret** ptr to init NSData:

```
[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:ret length:length_of_ret];?
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read bytes from file using `fread`.

```
FILE * ret = fopen( name, options);
void *data = malloc(bytes);
fread(data, 1, bytes, ret); 
fclose(ret);
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:bytes];
```

Comment: What "bytes" is? Size of ret-file? What do you mean "check return value,in case read was short!"? And will be data freed with NSData dealloc, or I must free it myself?

Comment: bytes is size of your file in bytes. NSData dealloc will work. NSData will take ownership of data.